# Select k numbers from each category without duplicates and maximize the selection

Tags: algorithm, np-complete

There are `N` lists of numbers.  Select `k` numbers from each list and return the largest set (no duplicates) that can be formed in this way.  If multiple sets of the same size are possible, returning any one of them is acceptable.

For example, if N = 3, k = 2,

```
l1: [1, 2, 3]
l2: [2, 7]
l3: [3]
```

Then the optimal result is `[1, 3, 2, 7]`. Pick `[1, 3]` from `l1`, pick `[2, 7]` from `l2`, pick `[3]` from `l3`. (Though there are other selections but the number of the elements in result set is less than this one, so this one is the *best* selection.)

I think this is a *NP-complete* problem and the only approach is enumeration.

Please shed some light on. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the problem well, but it seems that you can just add all the elements from all the lists to a set and get your maximal result in linear time, no? (then you can randomly pick `k` numbers from the result-set)

Comment: @alfasin then it doesn't grantee `k` numbers are selected. if l1 = [1,2], l2 = [3,4,5,6,7], if k = 2,  then randomly select 4 from [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] may return [4,5,6,7] which doesn't include 1,2 in l1. So in this case, the final result must contain [1, 2] from l1. Does it make sense?

Comment: But if you're looking for `max` solution you can't really do anything randomly...

Comment: @alfasin, Thanks for the follow up. In this case I mean the final result can be [1,2,3,4] or [1,2,4,7], both are accepted. And I want my algorithm to have this sort of randomization.

Comment: Sorry for not explaining myself well: if you want the maximal result, in your last example -  the answer *must* have `1,2` included. Since you have this restriction it's no longer "random".

Comment: @alfasin because it has only 2 elements (k == len(l1)). if l1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6], k = 2, then pick 2 from it could have different combinations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157689/discussion-between-alfasin-and-zsong).

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be solved with maximum bipartite matching. It is a classic algorithm and its description can be easily find on the internet, so I won't include it here.

Note that this algorithm is polynomial-time, so the problem is not NP-hard.

The bipartite matching problem is: given a bipartite graph, select a set of edges such that each vertex is adjacent to at most one selected edge, and among possible sets find one with maximum cardinality.

Let's build a bipartite graph. In the left part there will be a vertex for all distinct numbers which appear in the input. In the right part there will be `k` vertices per each list. Now, the "number" vertex is connected with all "list" vertices such that the list contains the number.

Now note that the cardinality of the maximum matching in this graph is exactly the answer for your problem: we've taken as many distinct numbers as possible without taking more than `k` from any single list. Here we allow taking less than `k` items from a list because it cannot increase the answer. You can take any extra (useless) items if necessary.

If you know something about maximum flows, you may consider adding only one vertex per each list, having `k`-capacity edge to sink. This is essentially the same but yields faster asymptotic running time.